# I need to Update my row with english version

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column which includes rows like this : MER.Fiyatlandırma Müdür Yardımcısı.

```
SELECT name, SUBSTR(
         name,
         INSTR(name, '.', 1, 1),
         INSTR(name, '.', 1, 2) + 1 - INSTR(name, '.', 1, 1)
       ) AS deneme
FROM   HR_ALL_POSITIONS_F;
```

I used this code and my rows looks like .Fiyatlandırma Müdür Yardımcısı.

Also ı have an excel file which includes .Fiyatlandırma Müdür Yardımcısı. this row and english version.

I need to change .Fiyatlandırma Müdür Yardımcısı. this to Price Vice Manager.

How can ı do that.

```
UPDATE denememusa123
   SET denememusa123.eklenecekkolon = (SELECT ENGLISHPOSITION FROM pozisyontanimlama)
 WHERE (SELECT SUBSTR (name,
                       INSTR (name,
                              '.',
                              1,
                              1),
                         INSTR (name,
                                '.',
                                1,
                                2)
                       + 1
                       - INSTR (name,
                                '.',
                                1,
                                1))
          FROM HR_ALL_POSITIONS_F) = (Select TURKISHPOSITION FROM pozisyontanimlama);
```

(I tired this but it is not working.
ora-01427:single-row subquery returns more than one row )

Help Please.

Comment: *but it is not working.* is not an error description. What is happening?

Comment: ERROR : ora-01427:single-row subquery returns more than one row

Comment: Add the error message to your question please. Also sample data are very helpful

Comment: And include table aliases into the query; you probably know which column belongs to which table, but we don't. As it looks like now, you're missing a **correlation** between table that has to be updated with another table(s).

Comment: It would be much better to understand (and to provide the answer) if you include some sample data (source table and translation table) in tabular format (using text formatting) and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `MERGE` statement:

```sql
MERGE INTO denememusa123 dst
USING (
  WITH split_denememusa123 (rid, prefix, position, suffix) AS (
    SELECT rowid AS rid,
           SUBSTR(
             eklenecekkolon,
             1,
             INSTR(eklenecekkolon, '.', 1, 1)
           ) AS prefix,
           SUBSTR(
             eklenecekkolon,
             INSTR(eklenecekkolon, '.', 1, 1) + 1,
             INSTR(eklenecekkolon, '.', 1, 2) - INSTR(eklenecekkolon, '.', 1, 1) - 1
           ) AS position,
           SUBSTR(
             eklenecekkolon,
             INSTR(eklenecekkolon, '.', 1, 2)
           ) AS suffix
    FROM   denememusa123
    WHERE  INSTR(eklenecekkolon, '.', 1, 2) > 0
  )
  SELECT s.rid, s.prefix || p.englishposition || s.suffix AS position
  FROM   split_denememusa123 s
         INNER JOIN pozisyontanimlama p
         ON (p.turkishposition = s.position)
) src
ON (src.rid = dst.ROWID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET dst.eklenecekkolon = src.position;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE denememusa123 (eklenecekkolon) AS
SELECT 'MER.Fiyatlandırma Müdür Yardımcısı.XYZ' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE pozisyontanimlama (turkishposition, englishposition) AS
SELECT 'Fiyatlandırma Müdür Yardımcısı', 'Price Vice Manager' FROM DUAL
```

Then after the `MERGE` the table contains:

| EKLENECEKKOLON |
| --- |
| MER.Price Vice Manager.XYZ |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jPXhSQEg)